# Remove all punctuation from the end of a string

Tags: java, regex, string

**Examples**:

```
// A B C.       -> A B C
// !A B C!      -> !A B C
// A? B?? C???  -> A? B?? C
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
while (endsWithRegex(word, "\\p{P}")) {
    word = word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
}
```

```
public static boolean endsWithRegex(String word, String regex) {
    return word != null && !word.isEmpty() && 
        word.substring(word.length() - 1).replaceAll(regex, "").isEmpty();
}
```

This current solution works, but since it's already calling `String.replaceAll` within `endsWithRegex`, we should be able to do something like this:

```
word = word.replaceAll(/* regex */, "");
```

Any advice?

Comment: Try `word = word.replaceAll("\\s*\\p{Punct}+\\s*$", "");`. It should remove all punctuation and will trim the string from the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using

```
\s*\p{Punct}+\s*$
```

It will match optional whitespace and punctuation at the end of the string.

If you do not care about the whitespace, just use `\p{Punct}+$`.

Do not forget that in Java strings, backslashes should be doubled to denote literal backslashes (that must be used as regex escape symbols).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/vFlacv)

```
String word = "!Words word! ";
word = word.replaceAll("\\s*\\p{Punct}+\\s*$", "");
System.out.println(word); // => !Words word
```

Comment: Wiktor, this doesn't seem to work for the following:   String word = "!Words word? - ";
See: http://ideone.com/DKSKAP

Comment: @SaqibAli: You can use [`"(\\p{P}+\\s*)+$"`](https://regex101.com/r/zG5lK1/2) to remove consecutive punctuation with whitespace. Or if you do not care about punctuation that much, use [`"[\\p{P}\\s]+$"`](https://regex101.com/r/zG5lK1/3) that will trim all strings on theright from spaces or punctuation or both.

Comment: Wiktor, how do I make it not remove parenthesis?

Comment: Replace `\\p{P}` with `[\\p{P}&&[^()]]`.

Comment: Be very careful! A statement like `(\\p{P}+\\s*)+$` can cause a [runaway regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: Correct, `"(\\p{P}+\\s*)+$"` is a bad pattern, I would have never suggested it now. This regex should be written as `"\\p{P}[\\p{P}\\s]*$"`. But I think `"(?U)[\\p{P}\\s]+$"` / `"(?U)[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\s]+$"` is what will work best for most users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("\\p{P}+$", "");
```

To include space also:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("[\\p{Space}\\p{P}]+$", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this, if you can take a minor hit in efficiency.

1. reverse the input string
2. keep removing characters until you hit an alphabet
3. reverse the string and return

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the logic of your method

```
public static boolean endsWithRegex(String word, String regex) {

        return word != null && !word.isEmpty() && word.matches(regex);
}
```

and your regex is : `regex = ".*[^a-zA-Z]$";`